# Error while writing data from python to redshift - Invalid date format - length must be 10 or more

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, amazon-redshift

I have a dataframe in python where date columns in datetime64[ns] data type. Now I am trying to write this data frame to redshift. I am getting following stl_load_errors:

```
Invalid date format - length must be 10 or more
```

All my dates are 2016-10-21 format, thus have length of 10. More over, I have ensured that no row has any messed up format like 2016-1-8 where it can have only 8 character. So the error is not making sense.

*Any one faced similar error while writing data to redshift ? Any explanation ?*

**Note:**
Here's some context. I am running the python script from EC2. This script writes the data in json format to S3 bucket and then this json is uploaded to an empty redshift table. The redshift table describes the date columns as 'date' format. I know there's another way which uses boto3/copy but for now I am stuck to this method.

Comment: Check the [STL_LOAD_ERRORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) table to get more details on the error. It will also show the value that it attempted to load.

Comment: I have provided the error reason above. 'raw field value'  or value attempted to load from the STL_LOAD_ERRORS table is blank.

Comment: Well, this suggests that you were trying to load blank data into a date field. Check the file you are loading.  You might also try using the [`ACCEPTANYDATE` parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-acceptanydate) in the COPY command.

Comment: Some of the date columns have huge number of NA or missing values, According to what you said that seems to be the only reason .

Comment: Yes. If the field does not contain a date (or a valid empty/null value), then an error would be generated. For example "NA" would generate an error. You'll either need to clean the data before loading it into Redshift, or load it into a Text column and then convert into a different Date column (eg via an UPDATE command).